# Laravel ORM with conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a table like it-

[image]

Model like it-

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class webinar_vote extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = array('webinar_id');
        protected $table = 'webinar_vote';
        protected $primaryKey='webinar_id';
        public $timestamps=false;
    }
```

What I want is,

1. If **$input['yes_no_value']** is 'yes', then increment **vote_yes** only
2. If **$input['yes_no_value']** is 'no', then increment **vote_no** only

And a model query like it-

```
    if('yes'==$input['yes_no_value'])
    {
        webinar_vote::firstOrCreate([
                                    'webinar_id' => $input['uuid']
                                ])->increment('vote_yes');
    }
    else
    {
        webinar_vote::firstOrCreate([
                                    'webinar_id' => $input['uuid']
                                ])->increment('vote_no');
    }
```

But the main problem is I can't get the first vote value.

When the entry is create, the data is not increased.

After it is created, it works just fine.

What I am doing wrong?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: When you use `firstOrCreate` and there are zero matches I get the impression that it creates a new record and doesn't execute the `increment()` or anything else chained onto the query. I would try using `firstOrNew` which will return a new model or the matched model, then you could increment it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm right in thinking this but I have a feeling that when using firstOrCreate, when no match is found and a new record is created, any chained methods are ignored.

If you use `firstOrNew` instead it will return an instance of the model if a match is found, or a new instance of the model when no match is found.

```
$webinarVote = webinar_vote::firstOrNew(['webinar_id' => $input['uuid']]); 

if('yes'== $input['yes_no_value'])
{
    $webinarVote->vote_yes = $webinarVote->vote_yes + 1;
}
else
{        
    $webinarVote->vote_no = $webinarVote->vote_no + 1;
}

$webinarVote->save();
```

Unrelated to your question, but worth noting that your class names aren't in keeping with the modern php standards. You should try and keep your naming conventions inline with Laravels, which follows [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) standards. Specifically:

> Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

I have accepted this and upvoted it